# MySql Return Table How to Handle in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, function

I have a MySql function which return a table (Int, Date, Symbol), but I am unable to get it working using Hibernate. I don't want to convert my mySql function to SP. 
Can some-one help me how I can get it resolved.